# event for all jQuery UI dialogs in a page

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to write a code for for example close event of all jQuery UI dialogs in a Page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible. You can do something like:

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").live("dialogclose", function() {
    // Do something.
});
```

Comment: Thank you, would you please explain 'live' event?

Comment: @shaahin, [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) allows to handle events on elements that do not match the selector (or do not exist at all) at the time the handler is bound. Since the `ui-dialog-content` class is added on the fly by jQuery UI when a dialog is created, I used `live()` so you don't have to wait for all the dialogs to be created before binding to the `dialogclose` event.